# Using sqlalchemy with psycopg

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, psycopg3

I am in need of combining the results of a SQLAlchemy query and a pyscopg query.

Currently I use psycopg to do most of my SQL selects in my code. This is done using a cursor and `fetchall()`.

However, I have a separate microservice that returns some extra `WHERE` clauses I need for my statement, based on some variables. This is returned as a SQLAlchemy [SELECT object](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select). This is out of my control.

Example return:

```sql
select * from users where name = 'bar';
```

My current solution for this is to hardcode the results of the microservice (just the `WHERE` clauses) into an enum and add them into the pyscopg statement using an f-string. This is a temporary solution.

Simplified example:

```py
user_name = "bar"

sql_enum = {
"foo": "name = 'foo'"
"bar": "name = 'bar'"
}

with conn.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute(f"select * from users where location = 'FOOBAR' and {sql_enum[user_name]}")
```

I am looking for a way to better join these two statements. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You say that the "microservice … returns some extra WHERE clauses … as a SQLAlchemy SELECT object" but the example you give is a complete literal SQL statement. So does this microservice really return a `<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select'>` object? If so, does that object have a `.whereclause` attribute? Please [edit] your question to provide more detail.

Comment: @GordThompson apologies for the confusion. The microservice returns the full statement (`<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select'>` object).

It does have an attribute `.whereclause` which returns just the bit I want, so thanks for that!

Now the question remains on how best to inject that where clause into the pyscopg statement

Answer (score 0):

Rather than mess with dynamic SQL (f-strings, etc.), I would just start with a SQLAlchemy Core `select()` statement and then add the whereclause from the statement returned by the microservice:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine("postgresql://scott:tiger@192.168.0.199/test")

users = sa.Table(
    "users", sa.MetaData(),
    sa.Column("id", sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column("name", sa.String(50)),
    sa.Column("location", sa.String(50))
)
users.drop(engine, checkfirst=True)
users.create(engine)

# mock return from microservice
from_ms = sa.select(sa.text("*")).select_from(users).where(users.c.name == "bar")

base_query = sa.select(users).where(users.c.location == "FOOBAR")

full_query = base_query.where(from_ms.whereclause)

engine.echo = True
with engine.begin() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(full_query)
    """SQL emitted:
    SELECT users.id, users.name, users.location 
    FROM users 
    WHERE users.location = %(location_1)s AND users.name = %(name_1)s
    [generated in 0.00077s] {'location_1': 'FOOBAR', 'name_1': 'bar'}
    """
```